# Python subprocess to invoke Python script stops working after PyInstaller

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller to create a .exe file. However when I run it on another computer, I am getting "python is not recognized as an internal or external command” error. I think this error is caused by the subprocess.run ("python",....) portion of the code (see below) since my other computer does not have python installed. What do I need to do instead to get this to work on computers that dont have python installed?

```
def ParseButtonClick():
     filepath = resource_path(ebx_filepath.get())
     folderpath = resource_path(ebx_savefolderpath.get())
    ** command = ["python",resource_path("main.py"),filepath,folderpath]
     subprocess.run(command, shell=True)**
     lbl_finished = Label(root,text = "Your file is ready! Enjoy!")
     lbl_finished.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

My understanding is that with PyInstaller, the user should not need to have python installed on their computer. And that subprocess.run ("python",....) is looking for in the environment PATH for python. I was thinking I should set the path to refer to the executable file, however this resulted in opening another instance of the program.

```
def ParseButtonClick():
     filepath = resource_path(ebx_filepath.get())
     folderpath = resource_path(ebx_savefolderpath.get())
**     pythonpath = sys.executable
     command = [pythonpath,resource_path("main.py"),filepath,folderpath]**
     subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
     lbl_finished = Label(root,text = "Your file is ready! Enjoy!")
     lbl_finished.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to run a `python` command from Python?  The way you run Python code within Python is to import a module and call functions within it.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm new to this so maybe there is a better route. More generally, I have a file that builds out a GUI using tkinter. When the user presses a button, I need it to run another python file called "main.py"

Comment: No, you DON'T need to run another Python file.  You just need to run some code from that file, which your already-running instance of Python can do just fine.